# SSRS Making a filter optional

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a report I am moving to SSRS from another reporting system.  It has a multi-select filter that the user can select one or more branches to filter the report by.  However, the branches presented to the user are limited to currently active branches.  The existing report had a second boolean parameter to fetch every branch - including inactive branches (which are not shown in the multi-select list).

Ideally, I would use an OR filter -- which SSRS strangely doesn't support.

Alternately, I tried to use a function in the filter as follows:

- Created a dataset AllBranches with a list of all branches
- Parameters used: Parameters!GetAllBranches = boolean and Parameters!Branch = user selected branches
- Attempted filter:  BRANCH in fx where fx = IIF(true= Parameters!GetAllBranches.Value, *return the list from the AllBranches query*, Parameters!Branch.Value)

I was unable to figure out how to return the list from the AllBranches query to make this strategy work.

How can I filter my data so that logically it returns every row were BRANCH in Parameters!Branch.Value -OR- user has set Parameters!GetAllBranches = true?

Comment: if you have access to the SQL, the format is `WHERE ThingToFilter = @Parameter OR @Parameter IS NULL`

Comment: You can use NULL as @JonTout mentioned or add an ALL to your selection and use similar logic `WHERE ThingToFilter = @Parameter OR @Parameter IS NULL`. If you want to use both parameters in an OR filter in an SSRS filter expression, `=IIF(Parameters!GetAllBranches = True OR Fields!Branch.Value = Parameters!Branch.Value, True, False)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sql stored procedure doesn't have a filtering parameter.  (For scope reasons, we don't want to change the Sql stored procedures so we don't introduce another source of errors.)  The filtering needs to be done within SSRS.